# 404 error in simple Spring project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am just started Spring MVC framerwork . I am trying do `helloworld` example but every tutorials i checked out , all have some problem that I do not know thats mean ! 
for example this project has 404 error when i click on `sayhello` :
I use eclipse Kepler and  tomcat 7.0 and Spring 4.0 ;
all Spring .jar files added in build path  .
controller :

```
    package net.spring3.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

spring-servlet.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.spring3.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp:

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Spring</title>
</head>
<body>${message}
</body>
</html>
```

index.jsp :

```
    <html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="hello.html">Say Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello.html")
```

The default `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` that is registered by the `DispatcherServlet` does not handle path extension mappings.

You could, alternatively, specify

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in your XML configuration, with the appropriate namespace. This will register a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` which maps your handlers to match extension mappings like `*.html`.

This tutorial seems bugged.

Comment: thank you ... can you suggest a good tutorial for learning Spring MVC?

Comment: @amir I don't like answering that because it makes me responsibly for something I don't control. I recommend you read the Spring MVC documentation, which is very detailed. Then write your own code, trying the various options detailed in the documentation. That's how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem before, if your server lead you to correct path WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp but that page is 404, it must tomcat blocked you page.

So what I did is move that page to /webapp/WebContent/jsp/hello.jsp and change your path for internalResuorceViewResolver to /WebContent/jsp

That should do the trick.